# Watchdog - on_modified event doesn't fire on codec file change

Tags: python, audio, ubuntu-14.04, codec, python-watchdog

I am trying to write a program that detects whether I have plugged in or unplugged my earphones and accordingly performs certain actions. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and through a bit of searching I found out that earphone/headset connection state is written out to a codec file at this path - /proc/asound/card0. The specific file that contains the state information is codec#0.txt.

I have written a Python program using the Watchdog library and tried to compare this codec#0 file output to an initial state of unplugged.txt. Depending on whether the files match, I want to launch a music player.

Now the code is as follows; I can't figure out why the on_modified event doesn't fire every time I connect/disconnect my earphones from the jack. I saw that the Modified Date for all files in the path mentioned above changes but my program doesn't print out a message.

Code:

```
import time
import os
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import filecmp

unpluggedStateFile = 'unplugged.txt'


class HeadsetPluginHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print 'File changed.'
        # os.system('cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 > pluggedIn.txt')
        # print filecmp.cmp(unpluggedStateFile, 'pluggedIn.txt')


if __name__== "__main__":
    event_handler = HeadsetPluginHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/proc/asound/card0',     recursive=False)
    observer.start()


    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        print 'stopped'
    observer.join()
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this doesn't work because watchdog can't monitor system files for changes. I'm not sure this is 100% correct but that's what I got from asking around on IRC, Reddit, etc.